# MYSQL: Retrieve all rows from one column containing multiple data

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've looked online for about two days and I'm not sure how to ask Google this scenario.  I'm trying to pull all rows from a single column that contain the word 'Helmet'.  What I'm getting is only 2 rows.  There's actually about 10 rows but it contains words like 'Legs, Helmet'  The rows that only have the word 'Helmet' are populating correctly.  Code I'm using.

```
  id | rune_slot
  ---------------------------------
  0  | Shoulders
  ---------------------------------
  1  | Chest
  ---------------------------------
  2  | Main Hand, Off Hand, Ranged
  ---------------------------------
  3  | Helmet
  ---------------------------------
  4  | Legs, Helmet
  ---------------------------------
  5  | Helmet
  ---------------------------------
  6  | Legs, Helmet
  ---------------------------------
```

As you can see, this is my table.  Like I said, I'm getting rows 3 and 4, but I can't seem to get rows 4 and 6 also.

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM runes WHERE rune_slot LIKE "Helmet"' ;

mysql_select_db('runelist');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(!$retval )
{
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
      echo "Rune Name : {$row['rune_name']} "." Craft Level :  {$row['craft_level']} "."   Rune Slot : {$row['rune_slot']} ".
      "<br />";
} 
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
```

This is the code I got from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_select_php.htm .

I've tried as many different select statements that I know of. I've tried changing mysql_fetch_array to _assoc and I've browsed the http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php .  I'm guessing it's bad practice to put multiple data in a single column?  Any help would be appreciated, I come here often to learn about PHP and MYSQL, now I'm just stuck.  Thanks!!

Comment: [you should probably stop using mysql_*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). Look at the red warning in your documentation link.

Comment: I did notice the warning, but when I tried to implement the new api type, I received an error message, at that point, I went back to the old style thinking it has not yet been implemented.  I'll rework the code to get it updated.  Thanks for the head up!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `%` in your query:

```
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM runes WHERE rune_slot LIKE "%Helmet%"' ;
```

which means any combination of `Helmet`

Comment: Wow, very easy.  I thought I already tried this, but apparently I didn't code it correctly.  Thanks for the help!  Another question I have after reading through some MYSQL documentation and websites, is it okay to fill in one column with CSV's? I'm reading that it doesn't conform to 1NF and I could have issues down the road.

Comment: You can, but searching like this in large tables could be slow in relational databases. if you have just a few list then there should be no problem but I suggest you to review your schema and use more relational approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing % in your like query.
Change query to like "%helmet%"